# MySQL schema for one table

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

When I need a table to set settings for my app. I always use table with many fields:

```
create table options (

 id ...
 url ...
 keys ..
 path ...

)
```

Of course I need one ID (because I have one settings)

Could I use other approach like:

```
create table options (

 id ...
 field ..

)
```

When `field` is for example:

```
`key => value`
```

So I don't need to set many fields ..

BS:
The fields have different types: `int` `text` `datetime` .. etc

Comment: u can save an array in string using serialize, in your server side, or with other delimiters, but you loose some good thing db can offer you such indexing , order by , group by ... on this fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do that. Just make sure you cast to the correct type when taking the values out of the database, and, similarly, when inserting or updating them.

PHP example:

```
// saving a settings value

$max_length = 20;
mysql_query("UPDATE settings SET value = '{$max_length}' WHERE field = 'max_length'");

// obtaining a settings value

$result = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM settings WHERE field = 'max_length'");
$settings = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$max_length = (int) $settings['value'];
```

For the above example, your schema will need a `field` (`varchar`) and a `value` (`varchar`).

Comment: Make `field` a `varchar`. When you insert or update, cast to string. When you select, cast to your original type.

Answer (score 0):

This is a better approach, otherwise if you want to add another setting you would need to change your model (database: add column) instead of just adding a row to an existing table.

Use:

- id
- key
- value

And possibly some other fields like type, required, ...

As type use Varchar and if you map a Setting (a DB-row) to a (Java, ...) Object provide methods like getValue(), getValueAsDate(), getValueAsBoolean(), ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
create table options (
OptionID string,
OptionType string,
OptionValue string,
)
```

then you need a function that will convert value to required type.

Comment: However, if you know, ate the moment of usage, type of your option, you can ignore 'OptionType' and specify target type in-place.

Answer (score 0):

> So I don't need to set many fields ..

you are able to issue an UPDATE statement that does not set every field.

```
update options set someval = 1 where id = 2;
```

this leaves all other values the way they were...